# Running lighttpd on ARM Platform

Tags: lighttpd

I am trying to host a web server on my ARM platform. The condition was that the web server should be light and fast. So I zeroed in on lighttpd. I was able to cross compile the lighttpd successfully for the ARM target. But when I am trying to run it on my arm platform it is giving an error:

```
-sh: /usr/bin/lighttpd: not found
```

I am using the following command to run the lighttpd.

```
/usr/bin/lighttpd -f /usr/bin/lighttpd.conf
```

I can't fathom what is the reason for such an error. The lighttpd executable is present at the correct location and I have executable permission. Can someone help me please.
I have tried to run the web server on Pentium target and it ran beautifully without any problems.

PS:- I have root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
file /usr/bin/lighttpd
```

Look at the output and make sure it's actually compiled for ARM. This error can happen if you're attempting to run an ELF executable that isn't compiled for the right architecture.

Comment: I have done a file on the lighttpd and it shows to be correctly compiled for ARM Architecture. I have one more query. Do we need to cross compile the shared libs used by lighttpd and put the .so in the target?